# Angularjs - how to access parent scope's variable by expression from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a custom directive:

`<my-directive attr="obj.property"></my-directive`

Where `obj.property` means `$scope.obj.property` from the parent scope.

My directive js:

```
return {
        restrict:'A',
        link:function(scope,elem,attrs){

            //scope[attrs.attr] won't work

        }
    };
```

Inside the link function, how do I access `$scope.obj.proprety` by the expression passed from `attr`?

`scope[attrs.attr]` won't work since it becomes `scope['obj.property']`. I want to get `scope.obj.property` out of `attrs.attr`.

Any idea? Or is there any other way to achieve my goal here? Note that it can't be isolated scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just:
    $parse(attrs.attr)(scope)

Comment: But how do I assign it a different value? I mean I would like to change to value of `scope.obj.property` inside the link function.

Comment: nvm. I found the answer: `$parse(attrs.attr).assign(scope,newValue);` Thanks!